# Open/close animation when visibility changes

Tags: wpf, expression-blend

I have a wpf application with a border control whose visibility is bound to a property on the viewmodel.

The control is shown and hidden as I would expect but I'd like to add some animation to make the show and hide visuals a bit smoother.
I'm thinking something along the lines of animating the width of the control between 0 and 250 - so it gives the appearance of expanding/shrinking.

I've had very little experience with blend so not sure if this is the right way to go about this but - I created a storyboard which does a scale transform on X and then tried to add a trigger against the visibility of the control to start the storyboard.. However, I can't find a visibility event to add to the trigger. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I'd always recommend using `Visual States` for this requirement https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee371169%28v=expression.40%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks,I'll look into this

Answer (score 1):

You can use style for border like that. But in that case you should bind to **IsEnabled** property instead of **Visibility**, because if visibility changes, opacitiy animation would not work.

```
<Style x:Key="myBorder" TargetType="Border">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard TargetProperty="Opacity">
                        <DoubleAnimation From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard TargetProperty="Opacity">
                        <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.ExitActions>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I hope, this is helpful.

**Update**

To shrink border you can use `ThicknessAnimation` for previous code sample.

```
<Storyboard TargetProperty="BorderThickness">
    <ThicknessAnimation From="1,1,1,1" To="0,0,0,0" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
</Storyboard>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'm trying to achieve a grow and shrink effect rather than a fade in/fade out one.

Comment: Updated answer for shrink|grow effect.

Comment: Thanks for this - I've actually used a double animation on the width to acheieve the effect I want.. Thanks again  for your help :)